# Why my script is not functioning like it had before?

Tags: autohotkey

My code was working fine until today(what it does now is nothing) and I didn't edit it at all today. any idea what might have happened?

**Code -**

```
loop
{
Send {1}
Send {2}

Numpad0::
ExitApp
Return
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't answered this before, but my problem was that my keyboard by default has my numpad assigned as macros.

Answer (score 1):

Your Syntax is off, should be like so:

```
loop
{
   Send {1}
   Send {2}
}

Numpad0::ExitApp
```

Comment: that makes the send thing work but when I press Numpad0 nothing happens

Comment: ok so I changed my code to this: loop
{
Send {1}
Send {2}

q::
ExitApp
} and now it works